# When is PCB thermal destruction desirable?

Tags: pcb, materials, dielectric

In the **[Wikipedia page for FR-4](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/FR-4)**, it contains this excerpt:

> FR-4 epoxy resin systems typically employ bromine, a halogen, to
> facilitate flame-resistant properties in FR-4 glass epoxy laminates.
> Some applications where thermal destruction of the material is a
> desirable trait[citation needed] will still use G-10 non flame
> resistant.

What are they talking about? Maxwell Smart self-destruct boards? I expect that valid reasons **do** exist.

I was investigating alternative composite materials for DIY PCB substrates for third world, especially including PET, the same material in polyester film caps, so if you know any, please let me know.

Comment: Missiles, rockets, bombs, and shells are what come to my mind.

Comment: I knew there had to be a valid, **good** reason.

Comment: Not necessarily weapons though. Any tech (still mostly millitary though) that you don't want to fall into the "wrong" hands, such as drones, satellites and such

Comment: What about ip or technology that you don't want other companies to steal?

Comment: @MicroservicesOnDDD I can't really think of non-military technology you don't want another company to steal, where they have the opportunity and means to intercept and steal it if it fails, that ends up in a flaming wreckage when it fails or explodes by design.

Comment: This message will self destruct in...